# Cannot read property '_resetForm' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

i am new on React and i've had a problem with this.

I have a form that should does an http request to save a form. Everytime a click the submit button, the application should call method _resetForm() and call the service, but isn't doing these stuff. I get this error when i comment 'this.produtoService.salvar(this.state)' : 'Cannot read property '_resetForm' of undefined' and, i get this error when i comment 'this._resetForm()' : 'Cannot read property 'produtoService' of undefined'. When i comment both, i get no errors.

```
const initialState = {
    nome: '',
    sku: '',
    descricao: '',
    preco: 0,
    fornecedor: ''
}

export default class CadastroProduto extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.nameInput = React.createRef();
        this.produtoService = new ProdutoService();
    }

    state = initialState;

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    _resetForm = () => {
        this.setState(initialState);
        this.nameInput.current.focus();
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this._resetForm();
        this.produtoService.salvar(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-header">Cadastro de Produtos</div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-6'>
                                <label>Nome:</label>
                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='nome' ref={this.nameInput} value={this.state.nome} onChange={event => this.onChange(event)} autoFocus></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-6'>
                                <label>SKU:</label>
                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='sku' value={this.state.sku} onChange={event => this.onChange(event)}></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-12'>
                                <label>Descrição:</label>
                                <textarea className='form-control' name='descricao' value={this.state.descricao} onChange={event => this.onChange(event)}></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-6'>
                                <label>Preço:</label>
                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='preco' value={this.state.preco} onChange={event => this.onChange(event)}></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-6'>
                                <label>Fornecedor:</label>
                                <input type='text' className='form-control' name='fornecedor' value={this.state.fornecedor} onChange={event => this.onChange(event)}></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-1'>
                                <button className='btn btn-primary' type='reset' onClick={this._resetForm}>Limpar</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-1'>
                                <button className='btn btn-success' type='submit'>Salvar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class ProdutoService {

    constructor() { }

    async salvar(produto) {
        AXIOS.defaults.headers.common = {}
        await AXIOS.post('http://localhost:3000/produtos', produto)
            .then(response => response)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            .finally()
    }
}
```

I would be happy if you helped me

Comment: Change `onSubmit` to an arrow function, or bind it in the constructor like so: `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)`

Comment: You are the best one, why the diference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onSubmit` event to the following.

```
 onSubmit= (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this._resetForm();
        this.produtoService.salvar(this.state);
  }
```

An alternative approach would be to bind `this` in your constructor.

```
   constructor() {
        // ... Your code here
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
```

The reason why your current setup is not working is because the `this` keyword used is scoped only to the onSubmit function.

Using an arrow function or binding the `this` keyword to onSubmit would allow the function to use the `this` of the class.